# En ce(s) moment(s) /instant(s), je ne veux pas y penser

Tags: sens, expressions, indications-de-temps

> En ces moments, je ne veux pas y penser. (1)
>
> En ces instants, je ne veux pas y penser. (2)
>
> En ce moment, je ne veux pas y penser. (3)
>
> En cet instant, je ne veux pas y penser. (4)

Les phrases (3) et (4) sont correctes dans le sens de *Je ne veux pas y penser maintenant*. Quelqu'un m'a dit que *en ces moments* et *en ces instants* ne s'emploient pas seuls, sans *-là*.

Je me demande quelle est la raison de cet usage. À mon avis, ces tournures devraient aussi être acceptables dans le sens de *actuellement* ou *en ce moment*. Sur Internet, j'ai surtout trouvé des phrases comme *Je compatis et pense à toi en ces moments de tristesse* ou *À vos côtés en ces moments difficiles*. Mais dans ces phrases-là, *en ces moments* devrait aussi signifier *au moment présent*, non ?

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a qu'un seul présent, qu'un seul « maintenant ». Le pluriel s'accommode donc mal avec « instant » et « moment » quand ils signifient respectivement « l'instant présent » ou « le moment présent ».

Au passé, au futur ou au sens large on peut utiliser le pluriel pour évoquer plusieurs instants ou périodes de temps ayant quelque chose en commun : « Ces instants de bonheur », « Ces moments de recueillement ».